# REF in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to prove that $S_2 = \{(1, 0, 2)^t,(−1, 1, 0)^t,(0, 1, 1)^t\}$ is a basis, which I write as :

$1,-1,0 \\
0,1,1 \\
2,0,1 $

I'm a bit confused as whether I should apply row or column operations? I automatically just go for row operations but does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

The answer will not depend on whether you use row or column operations, so you can choose the one which looks easier.

(The rank of a matrix and its transpose are identical, so using column operations is equivalent to using row operations on the transpose.)